# Segmentation fault when using BDW garbage collector

Tags: c, macos, garbage-collection, gdb, lldb

I'm trying to use the [Cesium3 parser combinator](https://github.com/wbhart/Cesium3/tree/combinators), and one of its dependencies is the [Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

I installed the BDW GC through Homebrew, with `brew install bdw-gc`.

Now, I run the sample calc program provided with Cesium 3, and run into a segmentation fault. Debugging with lldb reveals the following error:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xa6c16, 0x00000001000144e7 libgc.1.dylib`GC_malloc + 178, queue =
'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1000)
frame #0: 0x00000001000144e7 libgc.1.dylib`GC_malloc + 178
```

So, it looks like the problem is within the `GC_malloc` function, which is provided by the BDW GC.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.2. Any ideas on how to fix this problem, or get more information from the debugger?

Comment: Why the downvote? What other relevant information should I add?